# Maven property overriding conflict between parent/bom

Tags: spring-boot, maven, version, pom.xml, byte-order-mark

I am currently facing an issue with my maven configuration. I was thinking it will work in a way where versions in MyBom will have higher priority on the grand-grand-parent defined versions.

This is the setup :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6znq.png)

In spring-dependencies, I have this version <atomikos.version>**4.0.6**</atomikos.version>.
In myBom, I have this version <atomikos.version>**5.0.106**</atomikos.version>.

Both **spring-dependencies** and **MyBom** have the

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.atomikos</groupId>
        <artifactId>transactions-jta</artifactId>
        <version>${atomikos.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

I have imported the bom as usual in "MyParent":

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>myBom</artifactId>
        <version>${myBom.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
```

Finally, in "MyProject", when I am showing the effective pom, it uses the version **4.0.6** coming from the spring-dependencies.

I was expecting the version to be **5.0.106** as the bom redefine it in a sublayer.

Note that it can work with any dependency which is common between bom and parent.

So, currently, my only viable solution is to manually set the the version in "MyParent" which is making the creation of "MyBom" useless...

Can you confirm what is correct ? My assumption (meaning I have a misconfiguration somewhere) or the current behavior, meaning "MyBom" is worthless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible to override parents version from "MyBom" project. The only solution is to remove the spring-boot-starter-parent as parent and import the spring-dependencies at same level of "MyBom" import.

I found the solution but I would like to thank @J Fabian Meyer to also point the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, "direct" entries in the dependencyManagement always take precedent over BOMs, not matter what the inheritance level is.

You should probably just override the `<atomikos.version>` property.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your feedback but my goal is to have a "bom" which is the reference for all projects of my company. So, overriding directly the atomikos.version in the direct project is not my best solution. I wish I have a way to override the spring defaults version with my bom

Comment: Then you probably cannot use the spring boot starter parent.

Comment: Yes, in fact, this is not possible to achieve what I want to do. The only solution is to remove the spring-boot-starter-parent as parent and import the spring-dependencies like "MyBom". The order matters such 1st bom import has higher priority.

Answer (score -1):

The dependencyManagement is just a declaration of what the version of the dependency **should** be when **really** used as a project dependency. Thus you still should declare (use) the myBom dependency. Also, the scope "import" is invalid.
See the documentation

- https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#dependency-management
- https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependencies

Comment: Sorry, but this does not answer the question, and the scope `import` is perfectly valid in dependencyManagement.